# use custom collector with pylucene 2.9.4

Tags: java, python, lucene, nlp, pylucene

I'm trying to calculate high-PMI terms for a particular token in pylucene. A colleague gave me some Java code that works, but I am having trouble translating it into Python. In particular, the code relies on a custom collector. Here's the initial query code:

```
def __init__(self, some_token, searcher, analyzer):
    super(PMICalculator, self).__init__()

    self.searcher = searcher
    self.analyzer = analyzer
    self.escaped_token = QueryParser.escape(some_token)
    self.query = QueryParser("text",self.analyzer).parse(self.escaped_token)
    self.term_count_collector = TermCountCollector(searcher)
    self.searcher.search(self.query, self.term_count_collector)
    self.terms = self.term_count_collector.getTerms()
```

Here's the Term Count Collector class: http://snipt.org/vgGi8

This code breaks at `self.searcher.search` with the error:

```
File <filename>, line 26, in __init__
    self.searcher.search(self.query, self.term_count_collector)
lucene.JavaError: org.apache.jcc.PythonException: collect() takes exactly 2 arguments (3    given)
TypeError: collect() takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given)

    Java stacktrace:
org.apache.jcc.PythonException: collect() takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given)
TypeError: collect() takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given)

    at org.apache.pylucene.search.PythonHitCollector.collect(Native Method)
    at org.apache.lucene.search.HitCollectorWrapper.collect(HitCollectorWrapper.java:46)
    at org.apache.lucene.search.TermScorer.score(TermScorer.java:86)
    at org.apache.lucene.search.TermScorer.score(TermScorer.java:74)
    at org.apache.lucene.search.IndexSearcher.search(IndexSearcher.java:252)
    at org.apache.lucene.search.Searcher.search(Searcher.java:110)
```

I did some google searching, but to no avail - I am new at lucene, and can't tell if this is just not a feature that's supported by 2.9.4, or if it's a pylucene issue, or if my code is wrong. Please help!